# First and second derivative of a function log*(n) ("log star").

Tags: functions, derivatives, logarithms, discrete-logarithms

I would like to ask what are the derivative values (first and second) of a function "log star": $f(n) = \log^*(n)$?

I want to calculate some limit and use the De'l Hospital property, so that's why I need the derivative of "log star":
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\log_{2}^*(n)}{\log_{2}(n)}$$

More about this function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm

Comment: I don't think that "log*" is a standard function, or standard notation. Can you include a definition in your question?

Comment: That function is constant on a sequence of intervals, so it's derivative is $0$ everywhere, except at a sequence of increasing point that go to infinity, where the function is discontinuous (i.e. where it "jumps"), so it doesn't have a derivative there.

Comment: If you add more details about why you want this we might be able to give you some more helpful details.

Comment: Right now you're presenting an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You can't use l'Hopital here, but your _real_ question isn't about the derivative, it's about the limit you want to compute. I would suggest asking that instead.

Comment: OK, you`re right.

Comment: The limit is pretty clearly zero, since the $\log^*$ function grows exceedingly slowly.  The question is how most simply to prove that.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem.

Comment: I'd try to prove that for large enough $n$, $\log^*(n) \le 1 + \log(\log(n))$, which would easily lead to showing the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: take $n=2^m$ in your limit (and make sure you understand why you can do this!). Then (using $\lg(x)$ for $\log_2(x)$, which is a common convention) $\lg^*(n)=\lg^*(m)+1$, whereas $\lg(n)=m$. So your limit is $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\dfrac{\lg^*(m)+1}{m}$. But now we can take $m=2^r$, similarly, and get $\lim\limits_{r\to\infty}\dfrac{\lg^*(r)+2}{2^r}$. And since $\lg^*(n)\lt n$ for all $n\gt 1$ (this should be easy to prove) this gives you the limit you're after.

Comment: Nice reparamerizations!

Answer (score 0):

You might try to use the definition of derivative to find your solutions
$$
\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}
$$
and evaluate at the different intervals that are valid for the function.